# How to install sendmail in CentOS?

Tags: linux, smtp, centos, installation, sendmail

I want ask " how to manual install sendmail in CentOS " .
I can install it by command "yum install" , but i need install manual .

I went to the homepage http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/download/

and download the "sendmail.8.14.9.tar.gz" but do not know how to install It . I try unrar and type the command "./Build" but it is't work

Here is error :

```
/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/libsm
Configuration: pfx=, os=Linux, rel=2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64, rbase=2, rroot=2.6.32-431.el6, arch=x86_64, sfx=, variant=optimized
Making in /home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/libsm
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/libsm'
cc -O2 -I. -I../../include       -c -o assert.o assert.c
make[1]: cc: Command not found
make[1]: *** [assert.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/libsm'
Making all in:
/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/libsmutil
Configuration: pfx=, os=Linux, rel=2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64, rbase=2, rroot=2.6.32-431.el6, arch=x86_64, sfx=, variant=optimized
Making in /home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/libsmutil
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/libsmutil'
cc -O2 -I. -I../../sendmail   -I../../include  -DNOT_SENDMAIL      -c -o debug.o debug.c
make[1]: cc: Command not found
make[1]: *** [debug.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/libsmutil'
Making all in:
/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/libsmdb
Configuration: pfx=, os=Linux, rel=2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64, rbase=2, rroot=2.6.32-431.el6, arch=x86_64, sfx=, variant=optimized
Making in /home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/libsmdb
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/libsmdb'
cc -O2 -I. -I../../sendmail   -I../../include  -DNOT_SENDMAIL      -c -o smdb.o smdb.c
make[1]: cc: Command not found
make[1]: *** [smdb.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/libsmdb'
Making all in:
/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/sendmail
Configuration: pfx=, os=Linux, rel=2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64, rbase=2, rroot=2.6.32-431.el6, arch=x86_64, sfx=, variant=optimized
Making in /home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/sendmail
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/sendmail'
(cd ../../libsm; sh Build )
Configuration: pfx=, os=Linux, rel=2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64, rbase=2, rroot=2.6.32-431.el6, arch=x86_64, sfx=, variant=optimized
Making in /home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/libsm
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/libsm'
cc -O2 -I. -I../../include       -c -o assert.o assert.c
make[2]: cc: Command not found
make[2]: *** [assert.o] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/libsm'
make[1]: *** [/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/libsm/libsm.a] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/sendmail'
Making all in:
/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/editmap
Configuration: pfx=, os=Linux, rel=2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64, rbase=2, rroot=2.6.32-431.el6, arch=x86_64, sfx=, variant=optimized
Making in /home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/editmap
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/editmap'
(cd ../../libsm; sh Build )
Configuration: pfx=, os=Linux, rel=2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64, rbase=2, rroot=2.6.32-431.el6, arch=x86_64, sfx=, variant=optimized
Making in /home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/libsm
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/libsm'
cc -O2 -I. -I../../include       -c -o assert.o assert.c
make[2]: cc: Command not found
make[2]: *** [assert.o] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/libsm'
make[1]: *** [/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/libsm/libsm.a] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/editmap'
```

Please help me !! Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Oleksandr Kravchuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/186580/oleksandr-kravchuk) said, you need to link your gcc to cc. First try to execute below commands.

```
$ which gcc
```

If you have gcc packages on your server, you can see the output of your commands.

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
$
```

If you have root privileges, please make symbolic link of gcc to /usr/bin/cc.

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/cc
```

Then it'll be works.

Comment: thank :D  , i try to install and gcc , but now i'm having new problem , pls help me 
"cannot execute: Permission denied" and "make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/obj.Linux.2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.x86_64/libsm'"
I tried to "chmod 777 /home/duc/Desktop/sendmail-8.14.9/" , but it is'n work

Comment: The error message was not related with directory's ownership. I think that's related with your account's ownership. Could you try to type **sudo make**?

Answer (score 1):

It can't find C compiler:

> make[1]: cc: Command not found

The build system is reading value of CC environment variable, so assign it a path to your compiler, e.g.

> export CC=/usr/bin/gcc

Comment: thank you for answer , but i readed note "INSTALL" and i can't find how to install it . You mean i need creat "/usr/bin/gcc" ?

Comment: You need GCC then. Install GCC first. Try `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'` or google.